# Unclosed Quotation mark after the character string 'test'

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have been racking my brain with searching on the internet for the solution, but to no avail, I have been unsuccessful.

```
strSQL = "Update tTbl_LoginPermissions SET LoginName = '" & StrUserName & "', PWD = '" & StrPWD & "', fldPWDDate = '" & Now() & "'" & _
     "WHERE intLoginPermUserID = " & MyMSIDColumn0
```

Once I get the error out, I would like to actually use this where clause:

```
'WHERE intLoginPermUserID IN (SELECT intCPIIUserID From vw_ADMIN_Frm_LoginBuilder)
```

Here is the entire code:

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim strSQL As String
    Const cSQLConn = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=dbswd0027;UID=Mickey01;PWD=Mouse02;DATABASE=Regulatory;"

Dim StrUserName As String, StrPWD As String

'passing variables
StrUserName = FindUserName()
StrPWD = EncryptKey(Me.TxtConPWD)

    'Declaring the SQL expression to be executed by the server
     strSQL = "Update tTbl_LoginPermissions SET LoginName = '" & StrUserName & "', PWD = '" & StrPWD & "', fldPWDDate = '" & Now() & "#" & _
     "WHERE intLoginPermUserID = " & MyMSIDColumn0
     'WHERE intLoginPermUserID = ANY (SELECT intCPIIUserID From vw_ADMIN_Frm_LoginBuilder)

     Debug.Print strSQL
    'connect to SQL Server
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    With con
        .ConnectionString = cSQLConn
        .Open
    End With

    'write back
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = con
        .CommandText = strSQL
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .Execute
        Debug.Print strSQL
    End With

    'close connections
    con.Close
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing

       MsgBox "You password has been set", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "New Password"
```

NEWEST CODE Producing Error:

```
 '/Declaring the SQL expression to be executed by the server
    strSQL = "Update dbo_tTbl_LoginPermissions " _
    & "SET LoginName = '" & StrUserName & "' " _
    & "SET PWD = '" & StrPWD & "' " _
    & "SET fldPWDDate = '" & Now() & "' " _
    & "WHERE intLoginPermUserID = 3;"
```

I have gone to this site to try to figure out my mistake, but I still cannot figure it out:

Comment: What value ends up in `strSQL` ?

Comment: Try this `strSQL = "Update tTbl_LoginPermissions SET LoginName = '" & StrUserName & "', PWD = '" & StrPWD & "', fldPWDDate = #" & Now() & "#" & _
     "WHERE intLoginPermUserID = " & MyMSIDColumn0`

Comment: Hi!  My name is `Daniel'; DROP TABLE tTbl_LoginPermissions; --`.

Doesn't Access support prepared statements?  If so, you should be using those instead of manually fiddling with quotation marks.

Comment: Is it possible that any of the variables contain single quotes?

Comment: Use parameterized queries. Anything else is subject to SQL Injection. http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html

Comment: @HansUp: It's not entirely immune to SQL injection though: http://milo2012.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/sql-injection-for-microsoft-access/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much dilberation and help, it turns out the `FindUserName` that utilizes a Win32API function was not trimming the Username appropriately.
I changed it to the following:

```
Public Function FindUserName() As String
    ' This procedure uses the Win32API function GetUserName
    ' to return the name of the user currently logged on to
    ' this machine. The Declare statement for the API function
    ' is located in the Declarations section of this module.

    Dim strBuffer As String
    Dim lngSize As Long

    strBuffer = Space$(255)
    lngSize = Len(strBuffer)

    If GetUserName(strBuffer, lngSize) = 1 Then
        FindUserName = Left$(strBuffer, lngSize - 1)
    Else
        FindUserName = "User Name not available"
    End If

 End Function

Public Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
strSQL = "Update tTbl_LoginPermissions SET LoginName = '" & replace(StrUserName, "'", "''") & "', PWD = '" & replace(StrPWD, "'", "''") & "', fldPWDDate = '" & Now() & "'" & _
 "WHERE intLoginPermUserID = " & MyMSIDColumn0
```

Comment: I am trying to execute this simple code and it keeps giving me a Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'tlarse2'. I rewrote this bad boy for testing like this: 
'/Declaring the SQL expression to be executed by the server strSQL = "Update dbo_tTbl_LoginPermissions " _ & "SET LoginName = '" & StrUserName & "' " _ & "SET PWD = '" & StrPWD & "' " _ & "SET fldPWDDate = '" & Now() & "' " _ & "WHERE intLoginPermUserID = 3;"

Comment: Even though it gives me the following output screen: Update dbo_tTbl_LoginPermissions SET LoginName = 'tlarse2 ' SET PWD = '577 582 578 581 584 590 601 ' SET fldPWDDate = '11/6/2013 4:18:34 PM' WHERE intLoginPermUserID = 3;

Comment: I tried your Answer and it gave me the following output and still with the Run-Time Error:
Update tTbl_LoginPermissions SET LoginName = 'tlarse2 ', PWD = '577 582 578 581 584 590 601 ', fldPWDDate = '11/6/2013 5:45:42 PM'WHERE intLoginPermUserID =

Answer (score 0):

This was inevitably the code that corrected my (') mystery:

```
'/passing variables
StrUserName = FindUserName()
StrPWD = EncryptKey(Me.TxtConPWD)
StrUserId = Me.CboUser.Column(0)

 '/Declaring the SQL expression to be executed by the server
   strSQL = "Update tTbl_LoginPermissions SET " _
    & "LoginName = '" & StrUserName & "' , " _
    & "PWD = '" & StrPWD & "' ," _
    & "fldPWDDate = '" & Now() & "' " _
    & "WHERE intLoginPermUserID = '" & StrUserId & "'"
```